# android - interstitial ads only pop up on emulator

Tags: java, android, admob

In my app I want to show interstitial ads. After 10 games being played it should be shown, so I set a a counter to see how many games have been played. On my emulator the `int playcount;` resets and AdMobs test ad pops up. On a real device the `int playcount` keeps counting, and no ad is shown. What might be wrong with it?

```
public class GameScreen extends Activity {
public int playcount;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);    

    TextView playctv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    // set the ad unit ID
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();

    // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);


    SharedPreferences prefsplay = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);
    playctv.setText(String.valueOf(playcount));

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxx");
    AdRequest adRequestd = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();



}

public void restart(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    playcount++;

    SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
            .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount)
            .apply();

}


private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}



public void gameover() {

    if(playcount == 10) {

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial();
                playcount = 0;
            }
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("C04B1BFFB0774708339BC273F8A43708")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: because of this addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)

Comment: @KhalilM You think it will work if this part is deleted?

Comment: try to delete it and add AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

Comment: This part is inside onCreate, is it wrong placed there? Why is the variable counting more then 10 on a physical device, but not on emulator?

Comment: it depends on your need, here is a good example https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java

Comment: Okay, I try that one

Answer (score 2):

```
private void adView() {
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.activity_ad_view);
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.admob_banner_id));
    final AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Use this function to show ad instead of:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("C04B1BFFB0774708339BC273F8A43708")
                .build();
```

Problem is you are using the device id to in request ad and the device id is of emulator that's why the ad is only visible in the emulator.

Comment: It doesn't really help - no ads and the variable keeps counting and doesn't reset

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
package com.reducephotofilesize;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

public class GameScreen extends Activity {
    public int playcount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        TextView playctv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        loadAd();
        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        playcount = prefsplay.getInt("play_number", 0);
        playctv.setText(String.valueOf(playcount));

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-xxxxx");
        AdRequest adRequestd = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();


    }

    private void loadAd() {
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen));

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();

        // Load ads into Interstitial Ads
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}

    public void restart(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        playcount++;

        SharedPreferences prefsplay = this
                .getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount)
                .apply();

    }


    private void showInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        }
    }


    public void gameover() {

        if (playcount == 10) {
            showInterstitial();
            playcount = 0;
            loadAd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code seems a bit odd.

```
if(playcount == 10) {

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                showInterstitial();
                playcount = 0;
            }
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("C04B1BFFB0774708339BC273F8A43708")
                .build();
    }
```

`minterstittialAd` is being added a listener when `playcount` reaches a value of 10, everytime. Also, the value of `playcount` after reset isn't being saved into sharedpreference.

Remove the `mInterstitialAd.setAdListener()`, save the reset value of `playcount` into sharedpreferences and keep the remaining code as it is.

```
public void gameover() {
      if(playcount == 10) {
          showInterstitial();    
          playcount = 0;

          SharedPreferences prefsplay = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          prefsplay.edit().putInt("play_number", playcount).apply();


          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                // Check the LogCat to get your test device ID
                .addTestDevice("C04B1BFFB0774708339BC273F8A43708")
                .build();
      }
}
```

Comment: Works on emulator but on on real device - like the code can't be reached.

Comment: can you be a little more precise about the "code can't be reached" part. Seems as if the ad isn't being loaded on the actual device.

Comment: Yes exactly, and the variable playcount should reset after it has reached the value 10. On the emulator it does reset but on actual device it keeps counting and doesn't show ad - like the code is ignored completely

Comment: just saw it, value of playcount is being saved into sharedpref when incremented but not when it is reset to zero, due to this on real device too the ad should load at least once after a fresh install. updating the answer.

Comment: I get an error with the SharedPreferences - `Cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)'`

Comment: yes it should, since `this.getSharedPreferences()` is inside a listener `this` will return a listener context, remove `this` and use `getApplicationContext()` i.e. `getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences()` will solve the error.

Comment: Okay I noticed something: when playcount = 10 and the game is over I was waiting until the ad showed up, it takes a few seconds. When I close the ad and restart it, playcount resets. But when I'm not waiting for the ad and just click restart no ads are poping up,and playcount keeps counting

Comment: updated the answer, it should work perfectly now. The reset code of `playcount` is inside the listener, that's why the strange behavior. No need to wait till the ad loads, if the ad is already loaded it will be displayed else won't.

Comment: If I just remove the listener above the if-sentence the variable playcount resets, but no ad is shown - in logcat it says `Ad finished loading`, but it doesn't appear on emulator

Comment: have updated the code again, a few minutes ago. Is that what you tried?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now it just won't pop up but redet the value

Comment: does your game run on this activity itself, or is this activity called after when the game is over

Comment: Yes, it runs in this activity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132795/discussion-between-darshan-miskin-and-joe-s).